# Как изменить значения в TextAsset файле, который является Addressable?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Addressable имеется TextAsset(который Json). Мне нужно с ним взаимодейстовать: а именно менять значения в самом файле. Пытался сделать так:

```
public void M()
{
    var operationHandle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<TextAsset>("имя Json`а");
    TextAsset json = operationHandle.Result;
    var jObject = Deserialize(json);
    // jObject изменяется
    Serialize(jObject, json);
}

public static JObject Deserialize(TextAsset json)
{
    return (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.text);
}

public static void Serialize(JObject jsonObject, TextAsset json)
{
    var jsonTxt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(json), jsonTxt);
}
```

Здесь десериализуется Json файл, который затем изменятся, а после сериализуется обратно. Но в таком варианте происходит странная вещь: Json файл обновляет значения только тогда, когда происходит переключение с Unity на IDE.
Можно ли как-то написать по-другому изменение значений или как исправить проблему с обновлением Json`а?

Comment: `Json файл обновляет значения` а как вы проверяете, что он обновляет? И вообще, зачем `LoadAssetAsync` если можно как `File.ReadAllText` прочитать напрямую?

Comment: Тестами. Значения не изменяются. Но если переключиться на IDE, то файл сразу же поменяет значения на ожидаемые.